# Please explain $E = γmc^2$ more intuitively

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, mass-energy

My name is Shaun and I am 14 years old.

Lately I have been trying to learn about $E = mc^2$, and I came across *[Fermilabs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOCKNH0zaho)* video about $E = γmc^2$, where $γ$ is the Lorentz factor.

My question is how come $γ$, a ratio between the time an observer sees and a person who experiences that time, comes into the formula of energy-mass equivalence? It does not make sense intuitively, but plug and chugging fits.

Comment: I wanted to also ask about the constant γ itself. In Fermilabs video about γ , he mentions that the observer outside witnesses light going diagonally at the speed of c, therefore the speed of light from the flashlight to the window and back will be 2W/(sqrt(c^2 - v^2). How is that possible if the woman experiences a different speed (the light for her is going at the speed of light) BUT both observers experience the same speed for the light?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXxtqK7G4Uw is the link

Comment: I understand that you probably haven't studied special relativity yet, but the only way to really answer you would be to do such a study. Let just say that it's a consequence of the assumption that the speed of light is constant for any observer. If you want additional information, you should make your question more specific.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE. If you follow @Miyase's advice, you'll hopefully follow this. Contracting four-vectors with themselves gives conserved quantities of the form $A^2-\vec{B}^2$. We can do this with infinitesimal $dx^\mu$ or the four-momentum $P^\mu$. For your question, the trick is to compare the roles of $dx=c\beta dt,\,p=\beta E/c$ in$$d\tau^2=dt^2-dx^2/c^2=(1-\beta^2)dt^2,\,m^2=E^2c^{-4}-p^2c^{-2}=E^2c^{-4}(1-\beta^2),$$with $c\beta$ the speed so $1-\beta^2=\gamma^{-2}$. The first (second) calculation gives $dt=\gamma d\tau$ ($E=mc^2\gamma$).

Comment: *plug and chugging fits* Fits what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're trying to connect two things that are not (directly) connected.  That is total energy and time dilation.

The total energy ($E$) is the rest mass equivalent energy and the kinetic energy combined.  The rest mass is something the particle has at rest.  The kinetic energy is due to motion.

In Newtonian mechanics the kinetic energy is given by $E_K=\frac 1 2 mv^2$.

In special relativity the kinetic energy is $E_K=E-mc^2$, that is the total energy less the rest mass (energy).  But in special relativity the total energy is $E=\gamma mc^2$.

Now

$$\gamma=\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-\frac 1 2}$$

We can expand this expression out using a Taylor series (something you may not yet have studied in math).

$$\gamma=1+\frac 1 2 \frac{v^2}{c^2}+ ...$$

The "..." is standing in for more terms in higher powers of $\frac{v^2}{c^2}$

As you can possibly see now for small values of $v<<c$ we can ignore the higher power terms as they will always be much smaller than the first term.  The condition where $v<<c$ is typical for our everyday experience where Newtonian mechanics works fine.  But is special relativity we're concerned with conditions where that's not the case.

So our special relativity expression for $E_K$ is now :

$$E_K=E-mc^2=mc^2(\gamma-1)\approx \frac 1 2 mv^2$$

So this use of $\gamma$ in the expression for total energy is due to the contribution of kinetic energy corrected for special relativity.  There's no direct connection to time dilation and it's (sort of) a coincidence that the $\gamma$ factor appears in both formulas.  More precisely it's a result of having mathematically self-consistent formulas for things that depend on the relative motion of things.  The time dilation formula is a result of accepting that for this self consistency to work we have to treat time as something that also depends on the relative motion of things.

All of this self-consistency is linked together by the [Lorentz Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation), which is how we convert coordinates (including time) from one observer's reference frame to another observer's reference frame.  The Lorentz transform is absolutely central to understanding relativity and learning to apply it properly solves a lot of difficulties people have learning special relativity.

Comment: Thank you so much @StephenG - Help Ukraine !

Answer (score 0):

The $\gamma$-factor is the Minkowski spacetime analogue of the cosine function in Euclidean geometry.
(It’s trigonometry but with hyperbolic-trigonometry instead of circular-trigonometry.)

Think “cosine=adjacent/hypotenuse”.

An observer uses his 4-velocity to decompose any timelike unit-vector in Minkowski spacetime into (t,x)-components $(\cosh\theta,\sinh\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the rapidity(-angle) and $\tanh\theta=(v/c)$ of that unit vector.

When calculating the “time-component” of a 4-vector $\tilde W$ (e.g. a Spacetime displacement or a 4-momentum), one gets $|\tilde W|\cosh\theta$… that is $\gamma W$.

Time-dilation involves the time-component of a timelike displacement-vector.

Relativistic energy involves the time-component of a particle’s 4-momentum vector.

Answer (score -1):

> My question is how come γ, a ratio between the time an observer sees and a person who experiences that time, comes into the formula of energy-mass equivalence? It does not make sense intuitively, but plug and chugging fits.

The more energy a thing has, the more inertia the thing has.
The more inertia a thing has, the slower the thing oscillates.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks @stuffu